# ViewModel-less compose with model.bind in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am having a structure where the main view composes a partial view that composes another partial view in a repeater.

Example:

**main view**

```
<template>
    <h1>${factory.name}</h1>
    <div class="column">
        <compose view="./cars.html"></compose>
    </div>
</template>
```

**cars view**

```
<template repeat.for="car of factory.cars">
    <compose view="./specifications.html model.bind="{test: 'abc}"></compose>
</template>
```

**specifications view**

```
<template repeat.for="car of factory.cars">
    <h1>${$parent.$parent.factory.name} - ${car.name}</h1>
    ${test}
</template>
```

The problem I am facing is that the `model.bind` in compose doesn't work. I tried it with the `test` above, but what I'd actually want to pass there is `$parent.$parent.factory` so I can output `$parent.$parent.factory.name` in the `specifications view`.

(I know I can print it like this, but the scenario gets way more complicated so 
the binding is necessary)

Worth to mention that both `specifications` and `cars` view are viewmodel-less. Only the`main` view has a viewmodel where `factory` and `cars` are coming from.

[According to this page](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/10/aurelia-dynamic-composition/), what I am trying to do is possible, but I can't wrap my head about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: AFAIK, model.bind is instructing the engine to pass it to the activate of the view model, if you want to set binding context to it try with.bind

Comment: but then you'll loose your car context which is set by the repeat. I would add a VM and inject a factory there tbh.

Answer (score 1):

When composing with just an html file, the view-model for the referenced html file is the same as where the compose element is placed. In other words, it inherits the view-model of the parent. So you don't need to supply the model.

**main view**

```
<template>
    <h1>${factory.name}</h1>
    <div>
        <compose view="./cars.html"></compose>
    </div>
</template>
```

**cars.html**

```
<template>
  <div  repeat.for="car of factory.cars">
    <compose view="./specifications.html"></compose>
  </div>
</template>
```

**specifications.html**

```
<template>
    <h1>${factory.name} - ${car.name}</h1>
</template>
```

Take a look at this [GistRun example](https://gist.run/?id=f2fc7b2b0e62d83851bafe76765a86ec).

Comment: Indeed, but this won't work if each car object has it's own `factories`. Then, when doing a `repeat.for` on `cars.factories` in order to compose `specifications.html` then I'd lose my initial `factory` object.

Comment: What do you mean by "each car object has it's own factories"?

Answer (score 0):

What @Jeff G said is correct, but for my specific use-case what solved my issue was creating a simple view-model that I could use for all compositions. It's looking like:

```
export class Main {
    public parentFactory;

    public activate(data) {
        this.parentFactory= data;
    }
}
```

And in the view

```
    <compose
        view="./car.html"
        view-model="../view-models/main"
        model.bind="$parent.$parent.factory">
    </compose>
```